# In CPLEX, How can I use variables in forall loop syntax?

Tags: variables, linear-programming, cplex, forall, opl

I wanna use variables in cplex forall syntax like as below..

```
forall(j in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7})
{
  x[1][j] + x[1][(j+3)%7] + x[1][(j+4)%7] + x[1][(j+5)%7] + 
  x[1][(j+6)%7] + x[2][j] + x[2][(j+3)%7] + x[2][(j+4)%7] + 
  x[2][(j+5)%7] + x[2][(j+6)%7] >= 5;
}
```

But after I ran this script, there was a syntax eror because of (j+3)...
How should I make a script to use this algorithm?

Comment: What is the declaration of the array x[][]?
What error do you get?

Comment: I got syntax error because of j+4 in forall,

Comment: can't i use j+4 or j+3 in forall(j in) syntax?

Comment: could you paste the definition of x please?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to solve this, basically you need a function which takes the j index and the offset as parameter and return the corresponding result.

This could be done with a constant matrix that you set at the beginning for each of the 7 j and offsets.
Then inside the loop you refer to

```
x[1][ f[j][3] ]
```